# How to select a limited amount of values in a complex column in Hive?

Tags: dictionary, hive, hiveql

I have a table with an id, name and proficiency. The proficiency column is of a complex column with map data type. How do I limit the amount of data to 2 shown in the complex map data type?

Example table

```
ID  | name   | Proficiency
003 | John   | {"Cooking":3, "Talking":6 , "Chopping":8, "Teaching":5}
005 | Lennon | {"Cooking":3, "Programming":6 }
007 | King   | {"Chopping":8, "Boxing":5 ,"shooting": 4}
```

What i want to show after the select statement

```
ID  | name   | Proficiency
003 | John   | {"Cooking":3, "Talking":6 }
005 | Lennon | {"Cooking":3, "Programming":6 }
007 | King   | {"Chopping":8, "Boxing":5 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed number of map elements required this can be done easily using `map_keys()` and `map_values()` functions which return arrays of keys and values, you can access key and value using array index, then assemble map again using `map()` function:

```
with MyTable as -------use your table instead of this subquery
(select stack(3,
'003', 'John'  , map("Cooking",3,  "Talking",6 , "Chopping",8, "Teaching",5),
'005', 'Lennon', map("Cooking",3,  "Programming",6 ),
'007', 'King'  , map("Chopping",8, "Boxing",5 ,"shooting", 4)
) as (ID, name, Proficiency)
) -------use your table instead of this 

select t.ID, t.name, 
       map(map_keys(t.Proficiency)[0], map_values(t.Proficiency)[0],
           map_keys(t.Proficiency)[1], map_values(t.Proficiency)[1]
          ) as Proficiency
  from MyTable t
```

Result:

```
t.id    t.name  proficiency
003 John    {"Cooking":3,"Talking":6}
005 Lennon  {"Cooking":3,"Programming":6}
007 King    {"Boxing":5,"shooting":4}
```

Map does not guarantee the order by definition, and map_keys, map_values return unordered arrays by definition, but they are in the same order when used in the same subquery, so keys are matching to their corresponding values.